# What if variable of control_dependencies in cycle?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/training.py#L467), the logic is:

```
'''grads depend on total_loss'''
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(
    total_loss,
    variables_to_train,
    gate_gradients=gate_gradients,
    aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)

'''grad_updates depend on grads, so it also depend on total_loss'''
grad_updates = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

'''but total_loss depend on grad_updates'''
train_op = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([grad_updates], total_loss)
```

Look at the annotation, total_loss depend on grad_updates and grad_updates depned on total_loss, what will happen?